# Javascript - How to compare tables cell background color to specific color code

Tags: javascript

I am looping into html tables cell and I would like to check the cells color if it is equal to a specific color code.

if I alert 'cell.style.backgroundColor' I get the result of rgb(0,0,0)
But if I check it like this :

```
   if(cell.style.backgroundColor=="#000")
    {
      alert("ok");
    }
```

or this one :

```
    if(cell.style.backgroundColor=="rgb(0,0,0)")
     {
       alert("ok");
     }
```

I always get false.

Any ideas?

Comment: *"if I alert 'cell.style.backgroundColor' I get the result of rgb(0,0,0)"* If you really got that result, then your second attempt should have worked. But beware that different browsers will report this differently (`rgb(0,0,0)`, `rgb(0, 0, 0)`, `#000000`, `rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)`, ...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the spaces after the commas: `"rgb(0, 0, 0)"` not `"rgb(0,0,0)"`

Comment: It seems pretty weird, but worked. However I tested on Mozilla, Chrome, Edge. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Try it:

`window.getComputedStyle(cell, null).backgroundColor`

And test it in different browsers, maybe each one can get with different kind of format.